# What does transform: do in CSS to images?

Tags: css, transform

How does `transform:` and its values, such as `rotate` `scale` and `skew` etc get applied to the image?

Comment: Stack Overflow != Google

Comment: You should take a look ath the mdn page on transform: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: another one http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Comment: I find that the SO community gives clearer and more examples

Comment: Glad you like SO. But SO posts show up in Google, too. The idea here is to show some effort in the question you are asking. It's a programming *community*, not a research service, and should be respected as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First thing you need to understand is, there are a lot of self help available for basic things like your question. You should Google it before you ask to StackOverflow, where people spend their time to answer questions.

This one helps you a lot: [**3D Transforms in CSS**](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/perspective-01.html)

**Perspective**

[image]

**RotateX / RotateY**

[image]

**Card Flip**

[image]